# Why does django create a migration file when we change the storage attribute of FileField, when the storage type is not stored in the database?

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

I don't want to create a migration file whenever I change the storage of the FileField. I am getting the storage class from settings.py and it is configurable.

settings.py

```
Storage =  S3BotoStorage(bucket='example')
```

models.py

```
 from django.conf import settings

 class myModel(models.Model):
        file = models.FileField(upload_to='', blank=True, storage=settings.Storage)
```

Comment: If storage is not specified in settings then default storage is used and migrations are created. If I change the storage after an initial migration then a new migration file is created, which I don't want to happen.

Comment: Did you find an answer for this ? I have a similar issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Here is my interpretation to your question** - You want to use the storage class (which can be changed in future) specified in your settings.py to store the files.

Suppose you specify xyz storage class in your settings.py and run makemigrations. Django will create a migration file with storage attribute as the one you had specified in the settings.py.

Now if you change the storage class in the settings.py and do not run makemigrations and upload your file, your file will get uploaded to the new storage you specified in the settings file even if you do not run makemigrations.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes this would help but what if i run makemigrations in my build script?  Then migrations will be created.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I got the same problem. My local settings are different than other devs so each time someone does a migration the path changes in the migration file because of different paths

Answer (score 9):

**TLDR: It's an empty migration, it's harmless let it be reading any further or trying different things is probably just a waste of time**

When ever you make a change to a model django has to make a migration because it needs to keep track of what changes have been made to a model over time. However that does not always mean that a modification will be made in the database. The migration produced here is an empty one. Your migration probably looks something like this and you will say, hay that's not empty!!

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('stackoverflow', '0010_jsonmodel'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='jsonmodel',
            name='jfield',
            field=stackoverflow.models.MyJsonField(),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='parent',
            name='picture',
            field=models.ImageField(storage=b'Bada', upload_to=b'/home/'),
        ),
    ]
```

But it is!! just do

```
./manage.py sqlmigrate <myapp> <migration_number>
```

And you will find that it does not produce any SQL! Quote from the [manual](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/migrations/) as suggested by @sayse

> Django will make migrations for any change to your models or fields -
>   even options that don’t affect the database - as the only way it can
>   reconstruct a field correctly is to have all the changes in the
>   history, and you might need those options in some data migrations
>   later on (for example, if you’ve set custom validators).

Comment: @e4c5 sqlmigrate show the sql statement but i dont want the migration file to be created. Is that possible in anyway?

Comment: no it's not possible. refer to the updated answer. And why should having an empty migration be a problem at all?

Comment: Migrations in my use case will cause migration history conflicts.

Comment: how can that be so?

Comment: I have published a package with say 5 migrations on pyPi and now if someone installs that package and runs nake migration after changing the storage class then it will create a migration file number 6. And if i make any changes to the package and publish it again on pyPi with a new migration 6.There would be migration conflicts.

Comment: Ok i will try it out. Thanks for the help anyway.